# Handling images in react-native realm

Tags: javascript, image, react-native, realm

I have a list of products with each product having an `imageURL` field that points to a remote image. The products are persisted with realm. The challenge now is downloading the images and making them available offline.

How do I fetch images from remote URL and persist using realm?

Comment: An option might be to fetch the image, base64 encode it and save it in the db as base64 encoded.

Answer (score 3):

Realm React Native features a `data` property type, so you could save the image data directly to Realm if you wanted.

However, for large binary files that won't change often, we usually recommend you store the image files on disk, outside of Realm, and then simply have a string property in Realm referencing the name/path of that file.

After doing a quick search on GitHub, there appears to be [a React Native plugin](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs) that can manage downloading and storing files on disk.

My recommendation is that you use that library (or a similar one if you want) to download the image file to disk, and then store a reference to its file name in Realm, so you know which image file matches the Realm object. :)

Comment: There is this [(right now still open) issue on the linked RN filesystem access package](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs/issues/228) that points to the other package that does the same: [react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/). Both have about equal user numbers at least judging by the Github numbers.